# How to sync different nodes running the same process to maintain consistency in Cassandra

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, parallel-processing

My application is deployed on AWS with 3 nodes. When my application receives a request it can be forwarded to any node.

I have a scenario where based on some conditions I mark some request as pending and store them in Cassandra. And when this condition satisfies my process, it queries database and processes pending request. If there are no pending requests, process ends.

Now, the condition gets satisfied only on node 1 and my concern is what if I receive a request on node 2 and that request is marked as pending and just before inserting it in database, the condition on node 1 is satisfied and it queries database. Because node 2 has not inserted anything as yet, node 1 won't find any pending requests and process would stop and i wont be able to serve pending request received on node 2. Is there any way to avoid this??

Comment: I think for your use case, you will need to divide the problem into two parts. 1. Updating the status in a Queue and then return an interim response. You can set up a worker node to fetch the pending messages from Queue, process and update the database. If you still need to update the invoker with the processed status, you can either set up a different endpoint to Poll or use WebSockets (If the client is a web client) to push a message.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How is this specific to Cassandra? This could happen with relational database also right? In your case, as I understand there is a race between node1 and node2. Am I missing something?